# Retrieving values from multiple json in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I'd like to query some data stored in json in a relational Oracle table.

```
create table Foo (
  id VARCHAR2(40) not null,
  data CLOB,
  constraint foo_pk primary key (id),
  constraint foo_json_chk check (data is json)
);

insert into Foo (id, data) values ('1', '{"id": "1", "name": "bar1"}');
insert into Foo (id, data) values ('2', '{"id": "2", "name": "bar2"}');
```

I can query from one json using `json_table`:

```
select name from json_table(
  (select data from Foo where id='1'),
  '$'
  COLUMNS (
    name PATH '$.name'
    )
);
```

Gives

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| bar1 |
+------+
```

If we try to query from multiple rows:

```
select name from json_table(
  (
    select data from Foo --where id='1'
  ),
  '$'
  COLUMNS (
    name PATH '$.name'
    )
);
```

I'd like to obtain all the values matching the json path. For the data stored above this would mean:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| bar1 |
| bar2 |
+------+
```

Later on I will combine this query in a join with other tables in the system.

Unfortunately I get instead the following error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I've tried different combinations of `NESTED PATH` and of `JSON_ARRAYAGG` but no luck so far.

How can I extract values from several rows using the same json path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery in the json_table expression. List your source table in the from clause:

```
select name 
from   foo, json_table(
  data , '$'
  columns (
    name PATH '$.name'
    )
);

NAME   
bar1   
bar2
```

Comment: Brilliant, that fixes it, thank you!

Is there a good source that you would recommend for reference for json manipulation in Oracle?

Comment: I published an overview of [How to store, query, and create json documents in Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-store-query-and-create-json-documents-in-oracle-database) yesterday ;) If you want something more comprehensive, check out the [JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/index.html)